# Need help finding Display stone to finish Off the French Drain

Tags: outdoor, backyard, french-drain, rock

Where can I find stone like this to help finish off this French drain.
Can I find this at a big box store, or do I need to go to "stone seller"?
Also any other comments to make it look nicer.

I am kinda lost at where to go with this project that was started by an ex.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if this question would be considered off topic. Down under, garden and landscape suppliers would stock it. Or they may tell you who does sell them. Also, here, small quarries would sell them. But they look more like river stones.

Answer (score 1):

This is called "river rocks" or "river pebbles". In your setting they lie on top of gravel.
[image]

This is called "flagstone" or "sandstone":

[image]

How you want to finish that space is up to your taste, we can't really help with that. It is not an opinion website.

Answer (score 0):

River rocks would look great while new.

You have that hill that is a constant supply of mud, dirt.

Soon after the river rocks will be covered and you have to clean.

A small simple retainer wall would work here and then use some stepping stones for the rest to make the area pretty.

You can get all kind of retainer wall bricks at hardware store then just place them about 6 inches from the slope.